# Learn Python the Hard Way Ex 23 - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode

Fairly new to Python here, and working on Exercise 23 from Learn Python the Hard Way.

I'm having an issue running this code in Git Bash on a Windows comp, and I'm getting an error. Been racking my brain, wondering if it's my code or setting on my computer with the unicode characters.

**Here is my code**

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)


def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")

main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

**And here is the response I'm getting when running the program in Git Bash with the command**
[image: Response Code When Running Ex 23]

Comment: The link to the languages.txt file: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/languages.txt

Comment: This is a Windows problem, not a problem with the code. I will try to find the appropriate canonical. In the mean time, it will be helpful to indicate your Python version.

Comment: Please see Voy's answer [here](/questions/27092833). Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel. New to StackOverflow as well so I'll keep in mind in the future not to upload images. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I found a better duplicate (and added to my saved list).